# How can I validate the number of digits when converting from a string by chaining matches?

Tags: validation, rust

I just completed the [Programming a Guessing Game](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch02-00-guessing-game-tutorial.html) chapter of *The Rust Programming Language*. I now want to add validation for the number of digits  but couldn't find a pleasing way to do it.

I am able to achieve it by replacing

```
let guess: u32 = match guess.trim().parse() {
    Ok(num) => num,
    Err(_) => {
        println!("Please type a number.");
        continue;
    },
};
```

with

```
let guess = guess.trim();
if guess.parse::<u32>().is_err() || guess.chars().count() > 2 {
    println!("Please type a number from 1 to 100.");
    continue;
}
let guess: u32 = match guess.parse() {
    Ok(num) => num,
    Err(_) => continue, // this will never happen
};
```

The way I would prefer to do this is by somehow chaining matches, but I couldn't figure it out.

Comment: Why not check if the parsed number is within the range 1...100?

Comment: Because I didn't know of its existence and I didn't know you can check in Ok argument as I would do it in its body and that would mean printing the message on two places. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to chain match. You just need a different pattern:

```
let guess: u32 = match guess.trim().parse() {
    Ok(num @ 1...100) => num,
    _ => {
        println!("Please type a number within 1-99.");
        continue;
    },
};
```

This pattern means "If it's `Ok` and it has something bigger than 0 but smaller than 100, return its content, otherwise print message and continue."

Comment: The underscore by itself is always interpreted as Err?

Comment: @OliverTušla No, it is a wildcard. It matches against anything. But remember "match" construct match each pattern from first to last, and pick the first pattern that matches. So in effect it matches aganist anything not yet matched. You can think of it as the last "else" branch in a huge if-elseif-elseif-elseif...-else clause.

Answer (score 2):

You can chain matches like this:

```
let guess: u32 = match guess.trim().parse() {
    Ok(num) => match guess.chars().count() {
        1 | 2 => num,
        _ => {
            println!("Please type a number from 1 to 100.");
            continue;
        }
    },
    Err(_) => {
        println!("Please type a number.");
        continue;
    },
};
```

However, checking the string length is not what you really want. For example "00023" parses to "23" but has a strength length of 5.
Since you have access to `num` in this context, you can match on its value directly!

```
// ...
Ok(num) => match num {
    1..=100 => num,
    _ => {
        println!("Please type a number from 1 to 100.");
        continue;
    }
},
// ...
```